# Uppy "PUT" XHR(multipart/form-data) request results to empty Laravel $request array

Tags: laravel, api, xmlhttprequest, uppy

Hope you guys can help me. I'm using Uppy, with `XHRUpload` plugin, to upload a file but I'm getting an empty array of `$request` on the server side (Laravel) when I'm about to update a file using `PUT` request. I've tried method spoofing but still no luck. Here's my code...

I'm using `uppy.setMeta` by the way to add some additional data to the request.

```
    uppyUploader.setMeta({ 
      ...($(this).data('action') != 'store') && { _method: 'PUT' }, // Method spoofing of Laravel but the original method is 'POST'
      filename: $('input[name="filename"]').val(),
      ...
    });
    uppyUploader.upload();
```

but I got this in my update controller method's $request

```
$request->all(); // [] <-- empty array
```

Comment: Try `$request->allFiles();` to get the files from request.

Answer (score 1):

- To verify if the file is available in request you can use `$request->hasFile('filename')`
- To get the specific file from request you can use `$request->file('filename')` or `$request->filename`
- To get all files from request, you can use `$request->allFiles()`

---

> For more details check **Laravel Docs**:
> https://laravel.com/docs/master/requests#files

Comment: Your answer is not related to the question, I have same issue but your answer is not related to the real problem, also I did try all of them before reading your answer.

Comment: @Nazari Answer clearly shows how you can get the file from request. Additionally I have showed how to verify if file is available in request or not. If you check the last line of question you can see how he is trying to get the file.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that it was just a caching issue on the server side. Just notes to remember, if you're using XHR, you can easily set the method to `PUT`, but when you are using traditional forms, you have to make sure that you spoof the method using `@method('PUT')` and set the form method to `POST` as HTML5 forms doesn't support PUT method. Thanks for helping me out. Happy Coding.

Comment: Can you provide the solution?